# Monads in Haskell and Purity

Tags: haskell, io, monads

My question is whether monads in Haskell actually maintain Haskell's purity, and if so how. Frequently I have read about how side effects are impure but that side effects are needed for useful programs (e.g. I/O). In the next sentence it is stated that Haskell's solution to this is monads. Then monads are explained to some degree or another, but not really how they solve the side-effect problem.

I have seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4063778/in-what-sense-is-the-io-monad-pure) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3117583/is-haskell-truly-pure-is-any-language-that-deals-with-input-and-output-outside), and my interpretation of the answers is actually one that came to me in my own readings -- the "actions" of the IO monad are not the I/O themselves but objects that, when executed, perform I/O. But it occurs to me that one could make the same argument for any code or perhaps any compiled executable. Couldn't you say that a C++ program only produces side effects when the compiled code is executed? That all of C++ is inside the IO monad and so C++ is pure? I doubt this is true, but I honestly don't know in what way it is not. In fact, didn't Moggi (sp?) initially use monads to model the denotational semantics of imperative programs?

Some background: I am a fan of Haskell and functional programming and I hope to learn more about both as my studies continue. I understand the benefits of referential transparency, for example. The motivation for this question is that I am a grad student and I will be giving 2 1-hour presentations to a programming languages class, one covering Haskell in particular and the other covering functional programming in general. I suspect that the majority of the class is not familiar with functional programming, maybe having seen a bit of scheme. I hope to be able to (reasonably) clearly explain how monads solve the purity problem without going into category theory and the theoretical underpinnings of monads, which I wouldn't have time to cover and anyway I don't fully understand myself -- certainly not well enough to present.

I wonder if "purity" in this context is not really well-defined?

Comment: On the same topic: [The C language is purely functional](http://conal.net/blog/posts/the-c-language-is-purely-functional) by Conal Elliot

Comment: Well the IO type contains desciptions of actions "inside" the language whereas code generate from a C program is "outside" of the language itself (so the code is "pure" but not the language.)

Comment: @chi Thanks for the great link! I hadn't seen that before.

Comment: For getting the grasp of how this all plays together, I found reading the "original paper", [Imperative Functional Programming](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.53.2504) by Wadler/Peyton Jones, quite helpful (and understandable).

Comment: The main thing that makes it different from C++ is that *things are not in the IO monad by default*.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/4865616 .

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It's hard to argue conclusively in either direction because "pure" is not particularly well-defined. Certainly, *something* makes Haskell fundamentally different from other languages, and it's deeply related to managing side-effects and the `IO` type¹, but it's not clear *exactly* what that *something* is. Given a concrete definition to refer to we could just check if it applies, but this isn't easy: such definitions will tend to either not match everyone's expectations or be too broad to be useful.

So what makes Haskell special, then? In my view, it's the separation between **evaluation** and **execution**.

The base language—closely related to the λ-caluclus—is all about the former. You work with expressions that evaluate to other expressions, `1 + 1` to `2`. No side-effects here, not because they were suppressed or removed but simply because they don't make sense in the first place. They're not part of the model² any more than, say, backtracking search is part of the model of Java (as opposed to Prolog).

If we just stuck to this base language with no added facilities for `IO`, I think it would be fairly uncontroversial to call it "pure". It would still be useful as, perhaps, a replacement for Mathematica. You would write your program as an expression and then get the result of evaluating the expression at the REPL. Nothing more than a fancy calculator, and nobody accuses the expression language you use in a calculator of being impure³!

But, of course, this is too limiting. We want to use our language to read files and serve web pages and draw pictures and control robots and interact with the user. So the question, then, is how to preserve everything we like about evaluating expressions while extending our language to do everything we want.

The answer we've come up with? `IO`. A special type of expression that our calculator-like language can evaluate which corresponds to doing some effectful actions. Crucially, evaluation still works just as before, even for things in `IO`. The effects get executed in the order specified by the resulting `IO` value, not based on how it was evaluated. `IO` is what we use to introduce and manage effects into our otherwise-pure expression language.

I think that's enough to make describing Haskell as "pure" meaningful.

#### footnotes

¹ Note how I said `IO` and not monads in general: the concept of a monad is immensely useful for dozens of things unrelated to input and output, and the `IO` types has to be more than *just* a monad to be useful. I feel the two are linked too closely in common discourse.

² This is why `unsafePerformIO` is so, well, unsafe: it breaks the core abstraction of the language. This is the same as, say, putzing with specific registers in C: it can both cause weird behavior and stop your code from being portable because it goes below C's level of abstraction.

³ Well, mostly, as long as we ignore things like generating random numbers.

Comment: Also, if you're curious to read more, I wrote a longer [article](http://jelv.is/blog/Haskell-Monads-and-Purity) on this a while back which dives into more or less the same idea in more depth. By pure coincidence, it has almost the same title as this question :).

Answer (score 5):

A function with type, for example, `a -> IO b` always returns an identical IO action when given the same input; it is pure in that it cannot possibly inspect the environment, and obeys all the usual rules for pure functions. This means that, among other things, the compiler can apply all of its usual optimization rules to functions with an `IO` in their type, because it knows they are still pure functions.

Now, the IO action returned may, *when run*, look at the environment, read files, modify global state, whatever, all bets are off once you run an action. But you don't necessarily have to run an action; you can put five of them into a list and then run them in reverse of the order in which you created them, or never run some of them at all, if you want; you couldn't do this if IO actions implicitly ran themselves when you created them.

Consider this silly program:

```
main :: IO ()
main = do
  inputs <- take 5 . lines <$> getContents
  let [line1,line2,line3,line4,line5] = map print inputs
  line3
  line1
  line2
  line5
```

If you run this, and then enter 5 lines, you will see them printed back to you but in a different order, and with one omitted, even though our haskell program runs `map print` over them in the order they were received. You couldn't do this with C's `printf`, because it immediately performs its IO when called; haskell's version just returns an IO action, which you can still manipulate as a first-class value and do whatever you want with.

Answer (score 2):

I see two main differences here:

1) In haskell, you can do things that are not in the IO monad. Why is this good? Because if you have a function `definitelyDoesntLaunchNukes :: Int -> IO Int` you don't know that the resulting IO action doesn't launch nukes, it might for all you know. `cantLaunchNukes :: Int -> Int` will definitely not launch any nukes (barring any ugly hacks that you should avoid in nearly all circumstances).

2) In haskell, it's not just a cute analogy: IO actions are first class values. You can put them in lists, and leave them there for as long as you want, they won't do anything unless they somehow become part of the `main` action. The closest that C has to that are function pointers, which are quite a bit more cumbersome to use. In C++ (and most modern imperative languages really) you have closures which technically could be used for this purpose, but rarely are - mainly because Haskell is pure and they aren't.

Why does that distinction matter here? Well, where are you going to get your other IO actions/closures from? Probably, functions/methods of some description. Which, in an impure language, can themselves have side effects, rendering the attempt of isolating them in these languages pointless.

Comment: This seems to be arguing why haskell and functional programming are good, and contrasting with imperative programming. I agree, but that is not the question. I want to understand how haskell remains "pure" with monads (e.g. IO). In fact, it sounds like your #1 is saying that the IO monad is impure. I think haskell is great just with the weak claim that impurities are confined to monads like the IO monad. However, I *think* the claim of those smarter than me is that all of haskell, including monads like IO, is "pure". Maybe I don't know exactly what pure means here, or maybe it is ill-defined.

Answer (score 1):

---

fiction-mode: **Active**

It was quite a challenge, and I think a [wormhole](https://www.britannica.com/science/wormhole) could be forming in the neighbour's backyard, but I managed to grab part of a Haskell I/O implementation from an [alternate reality](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/qm-manyworlds):

```
class Kleisli k where
    infixr 1 >=>
    simple :: (a -> b) -> (a -> k b)
    (>=>)  :: (a -> k b) -> (b -> k c) -> a -> k c

instance Kleisli IO where
    simple = primSimpleIO
    (>=>)  = primPipeIO

primitive primSimpleIO :: (a -> b) -> (a -> IO b)
primitive primPipeIO   :: (a -> IO b) -> (b -> IO c) -> a -> IO c
```

Back in our slightly-mutilated reality (sorry!), I have used this other form of Haskell I/O to define *our* form of Haskell I/O:

```
instance Monad IO where
    return x = simple (const x) ()
    m >>= k  = (const m >=> k) ()
```

**and it works!**

fiction-mode: **Offline**

---

> My question is whether monads in Haskell actually maintain Haskell's purity, and if so how.

The monadic *interface*, by itself, doesn't maintain restrain the effects - it is only an interface, albeit a jolly-versatile one. As my little work of fiction shows, there are other possible interfaces for the job - it's just a matter of how convenient they are to use in practice.

For an implementation of Haskell I/O, what keeps the effects under control is that all the pertinent entities, be they:

- `IO`, `simple`, `(>=>)` etc

or:

- `IO`, `return`, `(>>=)` etc

are *abstract* - how the implementation defines those is *kept private*.

Otherwise, you would be able to devise "novelties" [like this](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/acme-realworld):

```
what_the_heck =
  do spare_world <- getWorld  -- how easy was that?
     launchMissiles           -- let's mess everything up,
     putWorld spare_world     -- and bring it all back :-D
     what_the_heck            -- that was fun; let's do it again!
```

(Aren't you glad our reality isn't quite so pliable? ;-)

This observation extends to types like `ST` (encapsulated state) and `STM` (concurrency) and their stewards (`runST`, `atomically` etc). For types like lists, `Maybe` and `Either`, their orthodox definitions in Haskell means no visible effects.

So when you see an *interface* - monadic, applicative, etc - for certain abstract types, any effects (if they exist) are contained by keeping its *implementation* private; safe from being used in aberrant ways.