# How Monads are considered pure?

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, monads, purely-functional

I am very much new to Haskell, and really impressed by the language's "architecture", but it still bothers me how ***monads*** can be pure.

As you have *any* sequence of instructions, it makes it an impure function, *especially* functions with I/O wouldn't be pure from any point of view.

Is it because Haskell assumes, like all pure functions, that `IO` function has a return value too, but in form of opcode or something? I am really confused.

Comment: Btw - where are you seeing this? Having the context would help in formulating an answer.

Comment: well, IO functions time to execute and also having interaction with user, like _getLine_ which not always but tend to have side-effect. How can that be pure?

Comment: The first step to understanding how I/O is managed is to recognize that `getLine` is *not* an I/O function. It is a constant with type `IO String`, which *represents* a program that can perform I/O.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28637146 .

Answer (score 24, accepted):

One way to think of this is that a value of type `IO a` is a "recipe", containing a list of instructions that if performed would have side effects. Constructing that "recipe" though, does not have any side effects. So a haskell program (whose type is `IO ()`) is basically a computation that constructs such a recipe. Importantly, the program does not execute any of the instructions in the recipe. When the recipe is completed the program terminates. Then the compiler (or interpreter) takes that recipe and executes it. But the code that the programmer wrote is not running anymore, so the instructions in the recipe are executed *outside the scope of the program*.

Comment: Simply, it's pure because (1) it will give the same output for the same input and (2) and when evaluated it does not have side-effects on other computations

Answer (score 12):

One way that "monads can be pure" is that they can represent pure expressions. I.e. in the List monad this:

```
do x <- xs
   return (x+1)
```

is the same as `map (+1) xs`.

Another way you can say "monads can be pure" is that Haskell distinguishes between *creating* a monadic computation and *running* the computation.

Creating a monadic computation is pure and doesn't involve any side effects. For instance, `replicateM 3 foo` will perform `foo` three times
as in `replicateM 3 (putStrLn "Hello, world")`. Purity allows us to reason
that `replicateM 3 foo` is the same as `do { foo; foo; foo }`. Note that this is true regardless of what kind of computation `foo` is - it could be a pure computation or one that involves some sort of effect.

Side effects only happen when you *run* the monadic computation. In the case of the IO monad this happens at run-time time when `main` is executed.
Other monads have their own "run" functions, i.e. `runReader` for the Reader monad, `runState` for the State monad, etc.

Answer (score 11):

Monads are not considered pure or impure.  They're totally unrelated concepts.  Your title is kind of like asking how verbs are considered delicious.

"Monad" refers to a particular pattern of composition that can be implemented on types with certain higher-kinded type constructors.  The entirety of the concept is tied up in the types of a couple operations and the rules for how those operations must interact with themselves and each other.

Few languages can express the concept usefully, since it's so abstract.  The only relatively common language other than Haskell that can is Scala. And it's actually relatively common in Scala too, though they call it `flatMap` for some reason.  Unsurprisingly, some types that support `flatMap` in Scala aren't pure.  They support `flatMap` 100% correctly, and they aren't pure.

The concepts are just not correlated.

Now, all that said, I understand where you're coming from.  Nearly every article on Haskell you see uses phrases like "the IO monad" or "uses monads to control effects" or other similar things.  The thing is, every use of terminology like that is deeply misleading.

`IO` is a type.  That's what's different from impure languages. IO operations are *values* of a particular type.  That's what allows Haskell to stay principled (in some ways) about purity, even while interacting with the outside world. Values of a particular type are built to describe interactions with the outside world.  Those values are pure, as described in the other answers.

So where does Monad fit into the whole thing?  Well, `IO` values need to be combined together to build up more complex IO actions from simpler ones. And it turns out that they way they combine together is exactly the kind of composition the `Monad` interface describes.  But so is combining lists with `flatMap`, or `Option` values with `andThen`.

The emphasis on `Monad` as something important, special, or interesting harms both the reputation of Haskell and its approachability for beginners. Especially since it's not important, special or interesting. The best comparison I can make is `Iterator` in Java. Yes, the language has some syntactic sugar for working with `Monad`/`Iterator`. No that doesn't come near implying that the language is unapproachable if you don't know the concept beforehand or that there's deep meaning involved that is necessary for entry into some super-secret society of enlightenment. When it comes down to it, neither idea is very deep or amazing. They're just very widely applicable, simple ideas that are easier to work with when you have a bit of syntactic sugar on hand.

Comment: _"Monad" refers to a particular pattern of composition that can be implemented on types with certain higher-kinded type constructors._ That is all there is to it! Explained in a single sentence. Thank you!

Answer (score 5):

[redbneb](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6776093/redneb)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39438091/how-monads-are-considered-pure/39438339#39438339) is almost right, except that for *Monads* the two timelines are *intermingled*, which is *their* essence;

a Haskell computation *does* take place after the outside world has supplied some inputs, say, in a previous computation step; to construct the *next* recipe ⁄ "computation descriptions", which is then *run* in its turn. Otherwise it would not be a Monad, but an *Applicative*, which constructs its recipes ⁄ descriptions from components known ahead of time.

And lowly *Functor* itself already has the two timelines (which is *its* essence): `IO a` value describes an "outside world's"  IO-computation "producing" an "inside" ⁄ pure  `a` result.

Consider:

```
[f x | x <- xs]             f <$> xs    Functor       [r |      x<-xs,r<-[f x]]
[y x | y <- f,  x <- xs]    f <*> xs    Applicative   [r | y<-f,x<-xs,r<-[y x]]
[r   | x <- xs, r <- f x]   f =<< xs    Monad         [r |      x<-xs,r<- f x ]
```

(written with monad comprehensions). Of course a Functor (Applicative / Monad / ...) can be pure as well; still there are two timelines ⁄ "worlds" there.

Few concrete examples:

```
~> [x*2 | x<-[10,100]]            
~> [r   | x<-[10,100], r <- [x*2]]           -- non-monadic
[20,200]                                     -- (*2) <$> [10,100] 

~> [x*y | x<-[10,100], y <- [2,3]]          
~> [r   | x<-[10,100], y <- [2,3], r <- [x*y]]        -- non-monadic
[20,30,200,300]                                       -- (*) <$> [10,100] <*> [2,3]

~> [r | x<-[10,100], y <- [2,3], r <- replicate 2 (x*y) ]
~> [r | x<-[10,100], y <- [2,3], r <- [x*y, x*y]]        -- still non-monadic:
~> (\a b c-> a*b) <$> [10,100] <*> [2,3] <*> [(),()]     -- it's applicative!
[20,20,30,30,200,200,300,300]

~> [r | x<-[10,100], y <- [2,3], r <- [x*y, x+y]]                -- and even this
~> (\a b c-> c (a*b,a+b)) <$> [10,100] <*> [2,3] <*> [fst,snd]   -- as well
~> (\a b c-> c a b)       <$> [10,100] <*> [2,3] <*> [(*),(+)]     
[20,12,30,13,200,102,300,103]

~> [r | x<-[10,100], y <- [2,3], r <- replicate y (x*y) ]  -- only this is _essentially_
~> [10,100] >>= \x-> [2,3] >>= \y -> replicate y (x*y)     --    monadic !!!!
[20,20,30,30,30,200,200,300,300,300]
```

Essentially-monadic computations are built of steps which can't be constructed ahead of the combined computation's *run-time*, because what recipe to construct is determined by the value resulting from a previously *computed* value -- value, produced by the recipe's computation when it is actually performed.

The following image might also prove [illuminating](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34545818/is-monad-bind-operator-closer-to-function-composition-chaining-or-functi/34561605#34561605):

[image: pipes image]

Comment: I would probably phrase it a bit differently, because my mental notion of a recipe can be monadic: "Add salt to taste."

Comment: @dfeuer I didn't quite get your point. My point is that adding salt is not monadic. If `f` is "adding" and `a` is "salt", then `f a` is "adding salt" already, before we talk of Monads or Functors even.

Comment: You missed the key "to taste". You taste the dish to decide if it needs more salt. Then you add salt iteratively, until it no longer needs more salt.

Comment: @dfeuer ah, yes, this process *is* essentially-monadic. But you could also just add pre-measured amount, according to your cook-book recipe. :) There's the usual mix-up here; that's why I prefer "computation description" (for `f a` things), and "c.d. constructors" (for functions `a -> f b`). Your "recipe" refers to the latter; redneb's "recipe" to the former.