# How does <*> derived from pure and (>>=)?

Tags: haskell, monads, functor, applicative

```
class Applicative f => Monad f where
       return :: a -> f a
       (>>=) :: f a -> (a -> f b) -> f b
```

`(<*>)` can be derived from pure and `(>>=)`:

```
fs <*> as =
    fs >>= (\f -> as >>= (\a -> pure (f a)))
```

For the line

```
fs >>= (\f -> as >>= (\a -> pure (f a)))
```

I am confused by the usage of `>>=`. I think it takes a functor `f a` and a function, then return another functor `f b`. But in this expression, I feel lost.

Comment: There are two instances of `>>=` there, which one is problematic?

Comment: I think the first one. But if anyone can explain the whole line, that will be great.

Comment: "I think it takes a functor f a and a function, then return another functor f b" that's not accurate. Try understanding the type of `>>=` first. Then choose an implementation of the monad type class and fill in the implementation step by step.

Comment: @pdexter is it really inaccurate? "Takes a functor" (`f a`) "and a function" (`a->f b`), "then return another functor" (`f b`). What exactly do you object to?

Comment: @n.m. it's not the most accurate explanation of `>>=` to somebody.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Lets start with the type we're implementing:

```
(<*>) :: Monad f => f (a -> b) -> f a -> f b
```

(The normal type of `<*>` of course has an `Applicative` constraint, but here we're trying to use `Monad` to implement `Applicative`)

So in `fs <*> as = _`, `fs` is an "f of functions" (`f (a -> b)`), and `as` is an "f of `a`s".

We'll start by binding `fs`:

```
(<*>) :: Monad f => f ( a -> b) -> f a -> f b
fs <*> as
  = fs >>= _
```

If you actually compile that, GHC will tell us what type the hole (`_`) has:

```
foo.hs:4:12: warning: [-Wtyped-holes]
    • Found hole: _ :: (a -> b) -> f b
      Where: ‘a’, ‘f’, ‘b’ are rigid type variables bound by
               the type signature for:
                 (Main.<*>) :: forall (f :: * -> *) a b.
                               Monad f =>
                               f (a -> b) -> f a -> f b
               at foo.hs:2:1-45
```

That makes sense. Monad's `>>=` takes an `f a` on the left and a function `a -> f b` on the right, so by binding an `f (a -> b)` on the left the function on the right gets to receive an `(a -> b)` function "extracted" from `fs`. And provided we can write a function that can use that to return an `f b`, then the whole bind expression will return the `f b` we need to meet the type signature for `<*>`.

So it'll look like:

```
(<*>) :: Monad f => f ( a -> b) -> f a -> f b
fs <*> as
  = fs >>= (\f -> _)
```

What can we do there? We've got `f :: a -> b`, and we've still got `as :: f a`, and we need to make an `f b`. If you're used to `Functor` that's obvious; just `fmap f as`. `Monad` implies `Functor`, so this does in fact work:

```
(<*>) :: Monad f => f ( a -> b) -> f a -> f b
fs <*> as
  = fs >>= (\f -> fmap f as)
```

It's also, I think, a *much* easier way to understand the way `Applicative` can be implemented generically using the facilities from `Monad`.

So why is your example written using another `>>=` and `pure` instead of just `fmap`? It's kind of harkening back to the days when `Monad` did *not* have `Applicative` and `Functor` as superclasses. `Monad` always "morally" implied both of these (since you can implement `Applicative` and `Functor` using only the features of `Monad`), but Haskell didn't always require there to be these instances, which leads to books, tutorials, blog posts, etc explaining *how* to implement these using only `Monad`. The example line given is simply inlining the definition of `fmap` in terms of `>>=` and `pure` (`return`)<sup>1</sup>.

I'll continue to unpack as if we didn't have `fmap`, so that it leads to the version you're confused by.

If we're not going to use `fmap` to combine `f :: a -> b` and `as :: f a`, then we'll need to bind `as` so that we have an expression of type `a` to apply `f` to:

```
(<*>) :: Monad f => f ( a -> b) -> f a -> f b
fs <*> as
  = fs >>= (\f -> as >>= (\a -> _))
```

Inside that hole we need to make an `f b`, and we have `f :: a -> b` and `a :: a`. `f a` gives us a `b`, so we'll need to call `pure` to turn that into an `f b`:

```
(<*>) :: Monad f => f ( a -> b) -> f a -> f b
fs <*> as
  = fs >>= (\f -> as >>= (\a -> pure (f a)))
```

So that's what this line is doing.

1. Binding `fs :: f (a -> b)` to get access to an `f :: a -> b`
2. Inside the function that has access to `f` it's binding `as` to get access to `a :: a`
3. Inside the function that has access to `a` (which is still inside the function that has access to `f` as well), call `f a` to make a `b`, and call `pure` on the result to make it an `f b`

---

<sup>1</sup> You can implement `fmap` using `>>=` and `pure` as `fmap f xs = xs >>= (\x -> pure (f x))`, which is also `fmap f xs = xs >>= pure . f`. Hopefully you can see that the inner bind of your example is simply inlining the first version.

Answer (score 5):

Applicative is a Functor. Monad is also a Functor. We can see the *"Functorial"* values as standing for computations of their "contained" ⁄ produced *pure* values (like `IO a`, `Maybe a`, `[] a`, etc.), as being the allegories of ⁄ metaphors for the various kinds of computations.

Functors describe ⁄ denote notions ⁄ types of computations, and Functorial values are reified computations which are "run" ⁄ *interpreted* in a *separate* step which is thus akin to that famous additional *indirection* step by adding which, allegedly, any computational problem can be solved.

Both `fs` and `as` are your Functorial values, and *bind* (`(>>=)`, or in `do` notation `<-`) "gets" the carried values "in" the functor.  *Bind* though belongs to Monad.

What we can implement in Monad with (using `return` as just a synonym for `pure`)

```
do { f <- fs ;       -- fs >>= ( \ f ->     -- fs  :: F (a -> b)   -- f :: a -> b
     a <- as ;       -- as >>= ( \ a ->     -- as  :: F  a         -- a :: a
     return (f a)    -- return (f a) ) )    -- f a ::         b
   }                                        -- ::     F       b
```

( or, with [MonadComprehensions](https://downloads.haskell.org/%7Eghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/glasgow_exts.html?monad-comprehensions#monad-comprehensions),

```
    [ f a | f <- fs, a <- as ]
```

), we get from the Applicative's `<*>` which expresses the same computation combination, but without the full power of Monad. [The difference is](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39647091/849891), with Applicative `as` is not dependent on the value `f` there, "produced by" the computation denoted by `fs`. Monadic Functors allow such dependency, with

```
    [ bar x y | x <- xs, y <- foo x ]
```

but Applicative Functors forbid it.

With Applicative all the "computations" (like `fs` or `as`) must be known "in advance"; with Monad they can be calculated -- purely -- based on the results of the previous "computation steps" (like `foo x` is doing: for (each) *value* `x` that the *computation* `xs` *will* produce, new computation `foo x` will be (purely) calculated, the computation that will produce (some) `y`(s) in its turn).

---

If you want to see how the types are aligned in the `>>=` expressions, here's your expression with its subexpressions named, so they can be annotated with their types,

```
exp = fs >>= g                                -- fs >>= 
      where  g f = xs >>= h                   --  (\ f -> xs >>=
                   where  h x = return (f x)  --           ( \ x -> pure (f x) ) )

 x   ::    a
 f   ::    a -> b
 f x ::         b
 return (f x) ::      F b
 h   ::    a ->       F b    -- (>>=) :: F a -> (a -> F b) -> F b
 xs  :: F  a                 --          xs     h
                             --           <-----
 xs >>= h ::          F b
 g f ::               F b
 g   ::   (a -> b) -> F b   -- (>>=) :: F (a->b) -> ((a->b) -> F b) -> F b
 fs  :: F (a -> b)          --          fs          g
                            --           <----------
 fs >>= g ::          F b
 exp ::               F b
```

and the types of the two `(>>=)` applications fit:

```
 (fs :: F (a -> b))  >>=  (g :: (a -> b) -> F b)) :: F b
 (xs :: F  a      )  >>=  (h :: (a       -> F b)) :: F b
```

Thus, the overall type is indeed

```
foo :: F (a -> b) -> F a -> F b
foo fs xs = fs >>= g                   -- foo = (<*>)
            where  g f = xs >>= h 
                         where  h x = return (f x)
```

---

In the end, we can see monadic bind as an implementation of `do`, and treat the `do` notation

```
     do {
```

abstractly, axiomatically, as consisting of the lines of the form

```
           a <- F a ;
           b <- F b ;
           ......
           n <- F n ;
           return (foo a b .... n)
        }
```

(with `a`, `F b`, etc. denoting *values* of the corresponding *types*), such that it describes the overall combined computation of the type `F t`, where `foo :: a -> b -> ... -> n -> t`. And when none of the `<-`'s right-hand side's expressions is dependent on no preceding left-hand side's variable, it's not essentially Monadic, but just an Applicative computation that this `do` block is describing.

Because of the Monad laws it is enough to define the meaning of `do` blocks with just two `<-` lines. For Functors, just one `<-` line is allowed ( `fmap f xs = do { x <- xs; return (f x) }`).

Thus, Functors/Applicative Functors/Monads [are EDSLs](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44118041/849891), *embedded* domain-specific languages, because the computation-descriptions are themselves *values* of our language (those to the right of the arrows in `do` notation).

---

Lastly, a types mandala for you:

```
                  T    a
                  T   (a  ->     b)
                      (a  ->  T  b)
                 -------------------
                  T          (T  b)
                 -------------------
                  T              b
```

This contains three in one:

```
       F   a                    A    a                  M   a
           a  ->  b             A   (a -> b)                a  ->  M  b
      --------------           --------------          -----------------
       F          b             A         b             M             b
```

Answer (score 1):

You can define `(<*>)` in terms of `(>>=)` and `return` because all monads are applicative functors. You can read more about this in the [Functor-Applicative-Monad Proposal](https://wiki.haskell.org/Functor-Applicative-Monad_Proposal). In particular, `pure = return` and `(<*>) = ap` is the shortest way to achieve an Applicative definition given an existing Monad definition.

See the type signatures for `(<*>)`, `ap` and `(>>=)`:

```
(<*>) :: Applicative f => f (a -> b) -> f a -> f b
ap    :: Monad       m => m (a -> b) -> m a -> m b
(>>=) :: Monad       m => m a -> (a -> m b) -> m b
```

The type signature for `(<*>)` and `ap` are nearly equivalent. Since `ap` is written using `do`-notation, it is equivalent to some use of `(>>=)`. I'm not sure this helps, but I find the definition of `ap` readable. Here's a rewrite:

```
  ap m1 m2 = do { x1 <- m1; x2 <- m2; return (x1 x2) }
≡ ap m1 m2 = do
    x1 <- m1
    x2 <- m2
    return (x1 x2)
≡ ap m1 m2 =
    m1 >>= \x1 ->
    m2 >>= \x2 ->
    return (x1 x2)
≡ ap m1 m2 = m1 >>= \x1 -> m2 >>= \x2 -> return (x1 x2)
≡ ap mf ma = mf >>= (\f -> ma >>= (\a -> pure (f a)))
```

Which is your definition. You could show that this definition upholds the [applicative functor laws](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/Applicative_functors#Applicative_functor_laws), since not everything defined in terms of `(>>=)` and `return` does that.