# Understanding (Traversable Product) Type

Tags: haskell

Given the following from [fp-course](https://github.com/data61/fp-course):

```
data Product f g a =
  Product (f a) (g a)

class Functor f where
  -- Pronounced, eff-map.
  (<$>) ::
    (a -> b)
    -> f a
    -> f b

class Functor f => Applicative f where
  pure ::
    a -> f a
  (<*>) ::
    f (a -> b)
    -> f a
    -> f b
```

I attempted to define the `Traversable` instance for `Product f g a`:

```
instance (Traversable f, Traversable g) =>
  Traversable (Product f g) where
  traverse :: 
    Applicative h =>
    (a -> h b)
    -> Product f g a
    -> h (Product f g b)  
  traverse fn (Product fa ga) = Product (traverse fn fa) (traverse fn ga)
```

The compiler shows an error:

```
src/Course/Traversable.hs:106:33: error:
    • Occurs check: cannot construct the infinite type: h ~ Product h h
      Expected type: h (Product f g b)
        Actual type: Product h h (f b)
```

I understand how my definition is wrong, but I don't understand how the actual type is `Product h h (f b)`.

Breaking apart `Product (traverse fn fa) (traverse fn ga)`'s type, I believe it is:

```
Product (h (f b)) (h (g b))
```

since `traverse`'s signature is `Applicative f => (a -> f b) -> t a -> f (t b)`.

Where does the `g` go per the actual type of `Product h h (f b)`? Please explain the above actual type.

Comment: You may find it a bit easier to define this particular instance using `liftA2` (an `Applicative` method exported by `Control.Applicative`) rather than `<$>` and `<*>`. I also strongly recommend using typed holes to work things out: `traverse fn (Product fa ga) = _ (traverse fn fa) (traverse fn ga)` will give you an error message that shows what you've gotten and what you still need to produce.

Comment: Thanks, @dfeuer! I've used type holes quite a bit on fp-course!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. You have

```
traverse :: (a -> h b) -> f a -> h (f b)
traverse    fn            fa  :: h (f b)   -- and,

traverse :: (a -> h b) -> g a -> h (g b)
traverse    fn            ga  :: h (g b)
```

Thus

```
Product (traverse fn fa)  (traverse fn ga) :: Product h h (f b)
        (h        (f b))  (h        (g b))
```

*where the equivalency `f b ~ g b` i.e. `f ~ g` has been forced,* because `Product p q t` is defined as

```
Product (p        t    )  (q        t    )
------------------------------------------
       p ~ h   t ~ f b    q ~ h    t ~ g b
```

So plainly applying `Product` to the two `traverse` results didn't pan out.

But the two have types `h (f b)` and `h (g b)`, and `h` is an Applicative, and we seek to create a result of type `h (Product f g b)`  with a *combined* type *on the inside of `h`*, so if only we could have

```
         h (f b)           h (g b)              h r              h s
        ---------------------------            ----------------------
         h (Combined  (f b)  (g b))             h (Combined   r    s)
```

and in fact since both `b`s are the same,

```
        ---------------------------
         h (Combined   f      g b )
```

so from `foo :: r -> s -> t` we want to get `bar :: h r -> h s -> h t`... If only there was [such a function ...](https://hoogle.haskell.org/?hoogle=%28Applicative%20h%29%20%3D%3E%20%28r%20-%3E%20s%20-%3E%20t%29%20-%3E%20%28h%20r%20-%3E%20h%20s%20-%3E%20h%20t%29&scope=set%3Astackage)

```
baz :: (Applicative h) => (r -> s -> t) -> (h r -> h s -> h t)
```

... and so the answer is `liftA2 Product (traverse fn fa) (traverse fn ga)`, applying the data constructor `Product` to the two traversals' inner results *"in"* (*"inside"*, *"under the covers of"*) the Applicative:

```
         h r       h s
           r   ->    s   ->   t
        ------------------------
         h                    t
```

Comment: I'm trying to help someone learn the basics of this "manual type inference" technique. I've seen you write an awful lot of these out. Do you think you could point to one that's a good *basic* example? Or a description somewhere of how to do it?

Comment: I don't now,  maybe [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14335704/how-to-infer-the-type-of-an-expression-manually/14558244#14558244), which I've found with [this search](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A849891+manual+prolog+type), or maybe [these answers](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A849891+manual+type+%5Bhaskell%5D) can be helpful. it all boils down to Modus Ponens of course (with some variations sometimes, like in this ["monadic](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51961192/849891) [type mandala"](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A849891+type+mandala)

Comment: so, basically, the "method" is just to write it out [in 2D](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69226553/849891), carefully, slowly, with consistent renaming to avoid name clashes. (one particular pet peeve of mine is the use of `f` for both "f"unction and "f"unctor... _awful_ thing, that).

Comment: ... and also, the equivalence of `f :: a -> b` and `f (x :: a) :: b`. (which is the same Modus Ponens thing of course).

Comment: Thanks for digging those up!