# In Haskell how to "apply" functions in nested context to a value in context?

Tags: function, haskell, apply, applicative

```
nestedApply :: (Applicative f, Applicative g) => g (f (a -> b)) -> f a -> g (f b)
```

As the type indicates, how to get that `(a->b)` applied to that `a` in the context `f`?

Thanks for help.

Comment: Hint: you only need `(Applicative f, Functor g)`.

Comment: First you need to lift an Applicative over the outer structure `g` so to get `f (a -> b)` into `f a -> fb`. HINT: `fmap (<*>) gfab`, `pure fa ~ g(fa)`

Comment: @Khundragpan Thank you for your help. I'm not sure whether I understand what you said. If I fmap (<*>) to gfab then I will get <*> applied to fab right? But what should I do next? Why I need to add a g to fa?

Comment: @Chaot1c `nestedApply gfab fa = (<*>) <$> gfab <*> pure fa`

Comment: @Khundragpan Thanks a lot for your help! Now I understand. I'm new to Haskell so the concept here is extremely confusing for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With

```
nestedApply :: (Applicative f, Applicative g) 
            => g (f (a -> b))  
            ->    f  a 
            -> g (f       b )
```

to get that `(a->b)` applied to that `a` in the context `f`, we need to operate *in the context* ***`g`***.

And that's just `fmap`.

It's clearer with the flipped signature, focusing on its last part

```
flip nestedApply :: (Applicative f, Applicative g) 
            =>    f  a 
            -> g (f (a -> b))     --- from here
            -> g (f       b )     --- to here
```

So what we have here is

```
nestedApply gffun fx = fmap (bar fx) gffun
```

with `bar fx` being applied *under the* ***`g`*** *wraps* by `fmap` for us. Which is

```
bar fx ::         f (a -> b)
            ->    f       b
```

i.e.

```
bar ::            f  a
            ->    f (a -> b)
            ->    f       b
```

and this is just `<*>` isn't it, again flipped. Thus we get the answer,

```
nestedApply gffun fx  =  fmap (<*> fx) gffun
```

---

As we can see only `fmap` capabilities of `g` are used, so we only need

```
nestedApply :: (Applicative f, Functor g) => ...
```

in the type signature.

---

It's *easy* when writing it on a sheet of paper, ***in 2D***. Which we imitate here with the wild indentation to get that vertical alignment.

<sub>Yes we the humans learned to *write* first, on paper, and to type on a typewriter, much later. The last generation or two were forced into linear typing by the contemporary devices since the young age but *now* the scribbling and talking (and gesturing and pointing) will hopefully be taking over yet again. Inventive input modes will eventually include 3D workflows and *that* will be a definite advancement. 1D bad, 2D good, 3D even better. For instance many category theory diagrams are much easier to follow (and at least imagine) when drawn in 3D. The rule of thumb is, it should be *easy*, not hard. If it's too busy, it probably needs another dimension.</sub>

Just playing *connect the wires* under the wraps. A few self-evident diagrams, and it's done.

---

Here's some type mandalas for you (again, flipped):

```
-- <$>               -- <*>               -- =<<
f     a              f     a              f     a       
     (a -> b)        f    (a -> b)             (a -> f b)
f          b         f          b         f    (     f b)   -- fmapped, and
                                          f            b    -- joined
```

and of course the mother of all applications,

```
--      $
      a
      a -> b
           b
```

a.k.a. [Modus Ponens](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modus_ponens) <sub>(yes, also flipped)</sub>.

Comment: You only need `Functor g`, as I pointed out in a comment.

Comment: @dfeuer perhaps we can add this as a final remark... I was more playing with the OP code, trying to show them how. I don't feel it is very important though, perhaps that's the signature they were given, so naturally Applicative is already a Functor.

Comment: @dfeuer of course it's superfluous. maybe I'll edit it in later (I don't like it when it says "...edited" instead of "...answered" in the feed, I feel with "answered" there's more chance someone will look at it at all and with "edited" there's less chance for that ... just a feeling I have)

Answer (score 5):

This one of those cases where it's helpful to focus on types. I will try to keep it simple and explain the reasoning.

Let's start with describing the task. We have `gfab :: g(f(a->b))` and `fa :: f a`, and we want to have `g(f b)`.

```
gfab :: g (f (a -> b))
fa   :: f a
??1  :: g (f b)
```

Since `g` is a functor, to obtain type `g T` we can start with a value `??2` of type `g U` and apply `fmap` to `??3 :: U -> T`. In our case, we have `T = f b`, so we are looking for:

```
gfab :: g (f (a -> b))
fa   :: f a
??2  :: g U
??3  :: U -> f b
??1 = fmap ??3 ??2  :: g (f b)
```

Now, it looks like we should pick `??2 = gfab`. After all,that's the only value of type `g Something` we have. We obtain `U = f (a -> b)`.

```
gfab :: g (f (a -> b))
fa   :: f a
??3  :: f (a -> b) -> f b
??1 = fmap ??3 gfab :: g (f b)
```

Let's make `??3` into a lambda, `\ (x :: f (a->b)) -> ??4` with `??4 :: f b`. (The type of `x` can be omitted, but I decided to add it to explain what's going on)

```
gfab :: g (f (a -> b))
fa   :: f a
??4  :: f b
??1 = fmap (\ (x :: f (a->b)) -> ??4) gfab :: g (f b)
```

How to craft `??4`. Well, we have values of types `f (a->b)` and `f a`, so we can `<*>` those to get `f b`. We finally obtain:

```
gfab :: g (f (a -> b))
fa   :: f a
??1 = fmap (\ (x :: f (a->b)) -> x <*> fa) gfab :: g (f b)
```

We can simplyfy that into:

```
nestedApply gfab fa = fmap (<*> fa) gfab
```

Now, this is not the most elegant way to do it, but understanding the process is important.