# What is the IO type in Haskell

Tags: haskell

I am new to the Haskell programming language, I keep on stumbling on the `IO` type either as a function parameter or a return type.

```
playGame :: Screen -> IO ()
```

OR

```
gameRunner :: IO String -> (String -> IO ()) -> Screen -> IO ()
```

How does this work, I am a bit confused because I know a String expects words and an Int expects numbers. Whats does the `IO` used in functions expect or Return?

Comment: Perhaps you should read an IO tutorial like the one at LYAH http://learnyouahaskell.com/input-and-output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Briefly put:

```
f1 :: A -> B -> C
```

is a function which takes two arguments of type `A` and `B` and returns a `C`. It does not perform any IO.

```
f2 :: A -> B -> IO C
```

is similar to `f1`, but can also perform IO.

```
f3 :: (A -> B) -> IO C
```

takes as an argument a function `A -> B` (which does not perform IO) and produces a `C`, possibly performing IO.

```
f4 :: (A -> IO B) -> IO C
```

takes as an argument a function `A -> IO B` (which can perform IO) and produces a `C`, possibly performing IO.

```
f5 :: A -> IO B -> IO C
```

takes as an argument a value of type `A`, an IO action of type `IO B`, and returns a value of type `C`, possibly performing IO (e.g. by running the IO action argument one or more times).

Example:

```
f6 :: IO Int -> IO Int
f6 action = do
   x1 <- action
   x2 <- action
   putStrLn "hello!"
   x3 <- action
   return (x1+x2+x3)
```

When a function returns `IO ()`, it returns no useful value, but can perform IO. Similar to, say, returning `void` in C or Java. Your

```
gameRunner :: IO String -> (String -> IO ()) -> Screen -> IO ()
```

function can be called with the following arguments:

```
arg1 :: IO String
arg1 = do
   putStrLn "hello"
   s <- readLine
   return ("here: " ++ s)

arg2 :: String -> IO ()
arg2 str = do
   putStrLn "hello"
   putStrLn str
   putStrLn "hello again"

arg3 :: Screen
arg3 = ... -- I don't know what's a Screen in your context
```

Comment: I am trying to run your example function but it fails:

`f6 :: IO Int -> IO Int
f6 action = do
   x1 <- action
   x2 <- action
   putStrLn "hello!"
   x3 <- action
   return (x1+x2+x3)`

Comment: @Oto-ObongEshiett How do you run it? What argument are you passing to it? Try, e.g. `f6 (do putStrLn "hi" ; return 12)`

Answer (score 7):

`IO` is the way how Haskell differentiates between code that is referentially transparent and code that is not. `IO a` is the type of an IO action that returns an `a`.

You can think of an IO action as a piece of code with some effect on the real world that waits to get executed. Because of this side effect, an IO action is not referentially transparent; therefore, execution order matters. It is the task of the `main` function of a Haskell program to properly sequence and execute all IO actions. Thus, when you write a function that returns `IO a`, what you are actually doing is writing a function that returns an action that eventually - when executed by `main` - performs the action and returns an `a`.

**Some more explanation:**

Referential transparency means that you can replace a function by its value. A referentially transparent function cannot have any side effects; in particular, a referentially transparent function cannot access any hardware resources like files, network, or keyboard, because the function value would depend on something else than its parameters.

Referentially transparent functions in a functional language like Haskell are like math functions (mappings between domain and codomain), much more than a sequence of imperative instructions on how to compute the function's value. Therefore, Haskell code says the compiler that a function is *applied* to its arguments, but it does not say that a function is *called* and thus actually computed.

Therefore, referentially transparent functions do not imply the order of execution. The Haskell compiler is free to evaluate functions in any way it sees fit - or not evaluate them at all if it is not necessary (called lazy evaluation). The only ordering arises from *data dependencies*, when one function requires the output of another function as input.

Real-world side effects are not referentially transparent. You can think of the real world as some sort of implicit global state that effectual functions mutate. Because of this state, the order of execution matters: It makes a difference if you first read from a database and then update it, or vice versa.

Haskell is a pure functional language, all its functions are referentially transparent and compilation rests on this guarantee. How, then, can we deal with effectful functions that manipulate some global real-world state and that need to be executed in a certain order? By introducing data dependency between those functions.

This is exactly what IO does: Under the hood, the IO type wraps an effectful function together with a dummy state paramter. Each IO action takes this dummy state as input and provides it as output. Passing this dummy state parameter from one IO action to the next creates a data dependency and thus tells the Haskell compiler how to properly sequence all the IO actions.

You don't see the dummy state parameter because it is hidden behind some syntactic sugar: the `do` notation in `main` and other IO actions, and inside the `IO` type.

Answer (score 0):

Let's try answering some simpler questions first:

- What is the `Maybe` type in Haskell?

  From chapter 21 (page 205) of the [Haskell 2010 Report](https://www.haskell.org/definition/haskell2010.pdf):

  ```
  data Maybe a = Nothing | Just a
  ```

  it's a simple partial type - you have a value (conveyed via `Just`) or you don't (`Nothing`).
- How does this work?

  Let's look at one possible `Monad` instance for `Maybe`:

  ```
  instance Monad Maybe where
      return = Just
      Just x  >>= k = k x
      Nothing >>= _ = Nothing
  ```

  This monadic interface simplifies the use of values based on `Maybe` constructors e.g.
  instead of:

  ```
  \f ox oy -> case ox of
                Nothing -> Nothing
                Just x  -> case oy of
                             Nothing -> Nothing
                             Just y  -> Just (f x y)
  ```

  you can simply write this:

  ```
  \f ox oy -> ox >>= \x -> oy >>= \y -> return (f x y)
  ```

  The monadic interface is widely applicable: from parsing to encapsulated state, and so much more.
- What does the `Maybe` type used in functions expect or return?

  For a function expecting a `Maybe`-based value e.g:

  ```
  maybe :: b -> (a -> b) -> Maybe a -> b
  maybe _ f (Just x) = f x
  maybe d _ Nothing  = d
  ```

  if its contents are being used in the function, then the function may have to deal with not receiving a value it can use i.e. `Nothing`.

  For a function returning a `Maybe`-based value e.g:

  ```
  invert :: Double -> Maybe Double
  invert 0.0 = Nothing
  invert d   = Just (1/d)
  ```

  it just needs to use the appropriate constructors.

  One last point: observe how `Maybe`-based values are used - from starting simply (e.g. `invert 0.5` or `Just "here"`) to then define other, possibly more-elaborate `Maybe`-based values (with `(>>=)`, `(>>)`, etc) to ultimately be examined directly by pattern-matching, or abstractly by a suitable definition (`maybe`, `fromJust` et al).

---

Time for the original questions:

- What is the `IO` type in Haskell?

  From section 6.1.7 (page 75) of the Report:

  > The `IO` type serves as a tag for operations (actions) that interact with the outside world.  The `IO` type is abstract:  no constructors are visible to the user. `IO` is an instance of the `Monad` and `Functor` classes.

  the crucial point being:

  > The `IO` type is abstract: no constructors are visible to the user.

  No constructors? That begs the next question:
- How does this work?

  This is where the versatility of the monadic interface steps in: the flexibility of its two key operatives - `return` and `(>>=)` in Haskell - substantially make up for `IO`-based values being
  abstract.

  Remember that observation about how `Maybe`-based values are used? Well, `IO`-based values are used in similar fashion - starting simply (e.g. `return 1`, `getChar` or `putStrLn "Hello, there!"`) to defining other `IO`-based values (with `(>>=)`, `(>>)`,  `catch`, etc) to ultimately form `Main.main`.

  But instead of pattern-matching or calling another function to extract its contents, `Main.main` is
  processed directly by the Haskell implementation.
- What does the `IO` used in functions expect or return?

  For a function expecting a `IO`-based value e.g:

  ```
  echo :: IO ()
  echo :: getChar >>= \c -> if c == '\n'
                            then return ()
                            else putChar c >> echo
  ```

  if its contents are being used in the function, then the function usually returns an `IO`-based value.

  For a function returning a `IO`-based value e.g:

  ```
  newLine :: IO ()
  newLine  = putChar '\n'
  ```

  it just needs to use the appropriate definitions.