# Understanding pure functions in Haskell with IO

Tags: haskell

Given a Haskell **value** (edit per [Rein Heinrich](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2225384/rein-henrichs)'s [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34280735/understanding-pure-functions-in-haskell-w-io?noredirect=1#comment56312971_34280735)) `f`:

```
f :: IO Int
f = ... -- ignoring its implementation
```

Quoting "Type-Driven Development with Idris,"

> The key property of a pure function is that the same inputs always produce the same result. This property is known as referential transparency

Is `f`, and, namely all `IO ...` functions in Haskell, pure? It seems to me that they are not since, `lookInDatabase :: IO DBThing`, won't **always** return the same value since:

- at t=0, the DB might be down
- at t=1, the DB might be up and `return MyDbThing` would result

In short, is `f` (and `IO ...` functions in general) pure? If yes, then please correct my incorrect understanding given my attempt to disprove the functional purity of `f` with my `t=...` examples.

Comment: Worth a read perhaps: http://chris-taylor.github.io/blog/2013/02/09/io-is-not-a-side-effect/

Comment: IO is done via monads. See [_What is a Monad?_](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/44965/what-is-a-monad) for an explanation of what those are.

Comment: I think understanding IO and understanding Monads are too often put in the same bucket — but they are distinct things; even independent, ultimately.

Comment: Actually, I/O *can* be implemented without monads. Early Haskell implementations did that, with sort of a "conversation" mechanism.

Comment: I think early Haskell IO was problematic though. Today, IO could also be implemented in terms of e.g. arrows I think, but then again arrows are also monads... I'd still argue in favor of teaching IO and monads separately though, starting with just IO, not mentioning it's a monad, and then eventually "discovering" it's a monad and that monads are more generally useful, and that IO is just a DSL, etc.

Comment: http://www.cis.upenn.edu/~cis194/spring13/lectures/08-IO.html too was a re-read

Comment: @ErikAllik: It'ld be worth mentioning in the first place that `IO` *is* pure and that `do` expressions have nothing to do with imperative programming before teaching newcomers about it ;). Thinking of it a bit, who was the genius who decided to incorporate such a misleading thing as `do` in Haskell?

Comment: What side of IO is pure? The Haskell side or the Haskell RTS side? It's pure from one angle and totally impure from the other.

Comment: `f :: IO Int` is not a function, it is a value. `lookInDatabase :: IO DBThing` doesn't return a value: it *is* a value. It is always the same value, so it is pure.

Comment: @ReinHenrichs: Haskell functions don't "return" a value. Instead, they get "applied" to a simpler function. Think of it for a moment. What disallows the `0` literal from being a function? It has type `Num a => a`, and so does `id $ 0`. That's one of Haskell's beauties; functions are sort of like templated values, and values are functions with no arguments. Thus, and taking currying into account, there's no purpose in diferentiating a function from a value, though it can be done anyways... BTW, `f :: IO Int` is a type delaration, thus neither a function or a value.

Comment: @KemyLand No. Values are not "functions with no arguments". Neither `0` nor `id $ 0` are functions. And yes, it is easy to differentiate a function from other values: functions are values whose type is constructed using `->`. And besides, functions *are* values.

Comment: @KemyLand It seems that others were able to understand "`f :: IO Int` is not a function" to mean "A value `f` of type `IO Int` is not a function". Why couldn't you? Is it because you are trying to find ways to prove that I am wrong rather than trying to engage in a good faith discussion? I am not interested in playing that game.

Comment: @KemyLand "Haskell functions don't "return" a value." You yourself say that functions return values in your own answer. You are obviously just trying to pick a fight.

Comment: @ReinHenrichs: Please don't take me wrong. I'm not trying to take a fight by no means. Actually, your last comments don't show any competence, profesionality and/or maturity. Why would you try to argument that I'm trying to "take you wrong"? I don't care if you're wrong or not, but whatever the OP learns from the question. This community is for helping each other, not to act in such a inappropiate way. And, you're right, I wrote an error in my answer, and I'll fix it. Thank you.

Comment: @ReinHenrichs: BTW, you said you don't want to "engage in that game", but the number of unread messages in my inbox button says otherwise.

Comment: Hey @ReinHenrichs - could you please elaborate on `It is always the same value, so it is pure`? I fully trust that you're right (from knowing your excellent podcasts and reputation), however how can my `t = 0, t = 1 ...` arguments (which I know aren't right) be disproved? Could you elaborate please?

Comment: @KevinMeredith An IO action is a "recipe" for performing IO that the runtime system must execute. The value in question is that recipe, and the recipe is always the same. For example, `getLine` is always the same recipe to read a line of input from stdin, and this does not change based on what is actually read when it is executed. And FWIW I am frequently wrong, so don't take what I say on faith.

Comment: @KevinMeredith This Haskell I/O tutorial was very helpful to me when I was first working through these things: http://www.vex.net/~trebla/haskell/IO.xhtml

Answer (score 11):

IO is really a separate language, conceptually. It's the language of the Haskell RTS (runtime system). It's implemented in Haskell as a (relatively simple) embedded DSL whose "scripts" have the type `IO a`.

So Haskell functions that return values of type `IO a`, are actually not the functions that are being executed at runtime — what gets executed is the `IO a` value itself. So these functions actually *are* pure but their return values *represent* non-pure computations.

From a language design point of view, IO is a really elegant hack to keep the non-pure ugliness completely isolated away while at the same integrating it tightly into its pure surroundings, without resorting to special casing. In other words, the design does not solve the problems caused by impure IO but it does a great job of at least not affecting the pure parts of your code.

---

The next step would be to look into FRP — with FRP you can make the layer that contains IO even thinner and move even more of non-pure logic into pure logic.

You might also want to read John Backus' writings on the topic of Function Programming, the limitations of the Von Neumann architecture etc. Conal Elliott is also a name to google if you're interested in the relationship between purity and IO.

---

P.S. also worth noting is that while IO is heavily reliant on monads to work around an aspect of lazy evaluation, and because monads are a very nice way of structuring embedded DSLs (of which IO is just a single example), monads are much more general than IO, so try not to think about IO and monads in the same context too much — they are two separate things and both could exist without the other.

Comment: What part of my answer was deemed incorrect or misleading by the downvoter?

Comment: Limitations of the Von Neumann architecture? We all know it's not perfect, but that's just too out of context. P.D: I'm not the downvoter.

Comment: John Backus and pure IO have a lot in common; Von Neumann is also relevant I think, but yes, perhaps a bit too broad here.

Answer (score 5):

First of all, you're right in noticing that I/O actions *are not* pure. That's impossible. But, purity in all functions is one of Haskell's promising points, so what's happening?

Whether you like it or not, a function that applies into a (may also be incorrectly said "returns a") `IO Something` with some arguments *will* always return the same `IO Something` with the same arguments. The `IO` monad allows you to "hide" actions inside of the container the monad acts like. When you have a `IO String`, that function/object does *not* contain a `String`/`[Char]`, but rather sort of a promise that you'll get that `String` somehow in the future. Thus, `IO` contains information of *what* to do when the impure I/O action needs to be performed.

After all, the only way for an `IO` action to be performed is by it having the name `main`, or be a dependency of `main` thereof. Because of the flexibility of monads, you can "concatenate" `IO` actions. A program like this... (note: this code is not a good idea)

```
main = do
    input <- getLine
    putStrLn input
```

Is syntatic sugar for...

```
main =
    getLine >>= (\input -> putStrLn input)
```

That would state that `main` is the I/O action resulting from printing to standard output a string read from standard input, followed by a newline character. Did you saw the magic? `IO` is just a wrapper representing what to *do*, in an impure context, to produce some given output, but not the *result* of that operation, because that would need the Haskell language to admit impure code.

Think of it as sort of a receipe. If you have a receipe (read: `IO` monad) for a cake (read: `Something` in `IO Something`), you know how to make the cake, but you can't make the cake (because you could screw that masterpiece). Instead, the master chief (read: the most basic parts of the Haskell runtime system, responsible for applying `main`) does the dirty work for you (read: doing impure/illegal stuff), and, the best of all, he won't commit any mistakes (read: breaking code purity)... unless the oven breaks of course (read: `System.IO.Error`), but he knows how to clean that up (read: code will *always* remain pure).

This is one of the reasons that `IO` is an opaque type. It's implementation is somewhat controversial (until you read GHC's source code), and is better of to be left as implementation-defined.

Just be happy, because you've been illuminated by purity. A lot of programmers don't even know of Haskell's existence!

I hope this has led some light on you!

Comment: "I/O actions are not pure."  But the rest of your answer is an argument that they *are* pure, which is correct. Perhaps you mean to say that the *execution* of IO actions is not pure.

Comment: @ReinHenrichs: They *can't* be pure. My argument is that I/O actions are not pure, but `IO` (as a monad and in-Haskell concept) is anyways.

Comment: What is "they"? The values themselves? The evaluation of these values? Both are pure. Execution of these values by the RTS is impure, in some sense, but no one is expecting execution to be pure.

Comment: @ReinHenrichs: Hi again, What do you mean? Please be more specific.

Answer (score 3):

Haskell is pulling a trick here. IO both is and isn't pure, depending on how you look at it.

On the "IO is pure" side, you're fallen into the very common error of thinking of a function returning an `IO DBThing` as of it were returning a `DBThing`. When someone claims that a function with type `Stuff -> IO DBThing` is pure they are *not* saying that you can feed it the same `Stuff` and always get the same `DBThing`; as you correctly note that is impossible, and also not very useful! What they're saving is that given particular `Stuff` you'll always get back the same `IO DBThing`.

You actually can't get a `DBThing` out of an `IO DBThing` at all, so Haskell don't ever have to worry about the database containing different values (or being unavailable) at different times. All you can do with an `IO DBThing` is combine it with something else that needs a DBThing and produces some other kind of `IO thing`; the result of such a combination is an `IO thing`.

What Haskell is doing here is building up a correspondence between manipulation of pure Haskell values and changes that would happen out in the world outside the program. There are things you can do with *some* ordinary pure values that don't make any sense with impure operations like altering the state of a database. So using the correspondence between `IO` values and the outside world, Haskell simply doesn't provide you with any operations on `IO` values that *would* correspond to things that don't make sense in the real world.

There are several ways to explain how you're "purely" manipulating the real world. One is to say that `IO` is just like a state monad, only the state being threaded through is the entire world outside your program;= (so your `Stuff -> IO DBThing` function really has an extra hidden argument that receives the world, and actually returns a `DBThing` along with another world; it's always called with different worlds, and that's why it can return different `DBThing` values even when called with the same `Stuff`). Another explanation is that an `IO DBThing` value is itself an imperative program; your Haskell program is a totally pure function doing no IO, which returns an impure program that does IO, and the Haskell runtime system (impurely) executes the program it returns.

But really these are both simply metaphors. The point is that the `IO` value simply has a very limited interface which doesn't allow you to do anything that doesn't make sense as a real world action.

Note that the concept of *monad* hasn't actually come into this. Haskell's IO system really doesn't depend on monads; `Monad` is just a convenient interface which is sufficiently limited that if you're only using the generic monad interface you *also* can't break the IO limitations (even if you don't know your monad is actually IO). Since the `Monad` interface is also interesting enough to write a lot of useful programs, the fact that `IO` forms a monad allows a lot of code that's useful on other types to be generically reused on `IO`.

Does this mean you actually get to write pure IO code? Not really. This is the "of course IO isn't pure" side of the coin. When you're using the fancy "combining IO functions together" you still have to think about your program executing steps one after the other (or in parallel), affecting and being affected by outside conditions and systems; in short exactly the same kind of reasoning you have to use to write IO code in an imperative language (only with a nicer type system than most of them). Making IO pure doesn't really help you banish impurity from the way you have to think about your code.

So what's the point? Well for one, it gets us a compiler-enforced demarcation of code that can do IO and code that can't. If there's no `IO` tag on the type then impure IO isn't involved. *That* would be useful in any language just on its own. And the compiler knows this too; Haskell compilers can apply optimizations to non-IO code that would be invalid in most other languages because it's often impossible to know that a given section of code *doesn't* have side effects (unless you can see the full implementation of everything the code calls, transitively).

Also, because IO is pure, code analysis tools (including your brain) don't have to treat IO-code specially. If you can pick out a code transformation that would be valid on pure code with the same structure as the IO code, you can do it on the IO code. Compilers make use of this. Many transformations are ruled out by the structure that IO code *must* use (in order to stay within the bounds of things that have a sensible correspondence to things in the outside world) but they would also be ruled out by any pure code that used the same structure; the careful construction of the IO interface makes "execution order dependency" look like ordinary "data dependency", so you can just use the rules of data dependency to determine the rules of using IO.

Comment: I really like and understand things better with your answer, and I quoted you in another answer, I hope you can read it and tell me if that's correct in your point of view :). https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47336203/is-print-haskell-a-pure-function/47336322#47336322

Answer (score 2):

Short answer: Yes, that `f` is referential transparent.

Whenever you look at it, it equals the same value.
But that doesn't mean it will always **bind** the same value.

Answer (score 1):

> In short, is `f` (and `IO ...` functions in general) pure?

So what you're *really* asking is:

#### Are `IO` definitions in Haskell pure?

> *You're really not going to like it.*
>
> Deep Thought.

[It depends on what you mean by "pure".](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69384679)

From section 6.1.7 (page 75) of the [Haskell 2010 report](https://www.haskell.org/definition/haskell2010.pdf):

> The `IO` type serves as a tag for operations (actions) that interact with the outside world. The `IO` type is abstract: no constructors are visible to the user. `IO` is an instance of the `Monad` and `Functor` classes.

the crucial point being:

> The `IO` type is *abstract*

If Haskell's FFI was sufficiently-enhanced, `IO` could be as simple as:

```hs
data IO a  -- a tag type: no visible constructors

instance Monad IO where
    return = unitIO
    (>>=)  = bindIO

foreign import ccall "primUnitIO" unitIO :: a -> IO a
foreign import ccall "primBindIO" bindIO :: IO a -> (a -> IO b) -> IO b
                        ⋮
```

No Haskell definitions whatsoever: all I/O-related activity is performed by calls to foreign code, usually written in the same language as the Haskell implementation. A variation of this approach
[is used in Agda](http://www.cse.chalmers.se/%7Eulfn/papers/afp08/tutorial.pdf):

> **4  Compiling Agda programs**
>
> This section deals with the topic of getting Agda programs to interact
> with the real world. Type checking Agda programs requires evaluating
> arbitrary terms, ans as long as all terms are pure and normalizing this is
> not a problem, but what happens when we introduce side effects? Clearly,
> we don't want side effects to happen at compile time. Another question is
> what primitives the language should provide for constructing side effecting
> programs. In Agda, these problems are solved by *allowing arbitrary
> Haskell functions to be imported as axioms*. At compile time, these imported
> functions have no reduction behaviour, *only at run time is the
> Haskell function executed*.

<sup>(emphasis by me.)</sup>

By moving the problem of I/O outside of Haskell or Agda, questions of "purity" are now a matter for that other language (or languages!).

Given these circumstances, there can be no "standard definition" for `IO`, so there's no common way to determine such a property for that type, let alone any of its expressions. We can't even provide a simple proof that `IO` is monadic (i.e. it satisfies the [monad laws](https://wiki.haskell.org/Monad_laws)) as `return` and `(>>=)`  simply *cannot* be defined in standard Haskell 2010.

To get some idea on how this affects the determining of various `IO`-related properties, see:

- [Semantics of *fixIO*](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.15.736&rep=rep1&type=pdf) by Levent Erkok, John Launchbury and Andrew Moran.
- [Tackling the Awkward Squad: …](https://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.13.9123&rep=rep1&type=pdf) by Simon Peyton Jones (starting from section 3.2 on page 20).

So when you next hear or read about Haskell being "referentially transparent" or "purely functional", you now know that (at least for I/O) they're just conjectures - no *actual* standard definition means there's no way to prove or disprove them.

(If you're now wondering how Haskell got into this state, I provide some more details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62557499).)