# How can passing the `IO ()` to `main` be considered pure?

Tags: haskell, io, programming-languages, pure-function

I don't quite understand how printing (outputting to the screen) can be considered pure in a programming languages sense, but I was claimed to that such a concept exists in Haskell.

You create an `IO ()` object via `print`, and you pass it to `main`, which does the printing for you.

My question: how can invoking `main` to perform such an impure action in itself be considered pure? Even if you claim `main` exists outside your Haskell program, you are still invoking it to perform a side effect.

Comment: An `IO ()` is a recipe for an action, not the action itself.

Comment: Right, but you cause the action by passing the recipe to `main` @LouisWasserman

Comment: I think most people understand it similar to Louis' explanation, in that `main` doesn't actually perform the operations you've described, but is rather returning some description which ~the mysterious runtime~ will evaluate and perform for you, meaning any function which yields an `IO a` is still pure. Like most programming languages, `main` isn't actually the real entry point, so as far as you're concerned there could be a method calling `main` for you which is basically just `start = unsafePerformIO main`. It's a matter of perspective in my opinion

Comment: On it being a matter of perspective, as @mitch_ puts it, see also [Ben's answer to *Understanding pure functions in Haskell with IO*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34283694/2751851).

Comment: Yes, there's a sense in which it's all a giant trick and can't "really" be pure. But it's at least a *useful* trick. The point of it is to end up with a programming model that is *consistent* with an interpretation in which `IO` is pure; if we really did have a universe simulator and implemented `IO` by world-passing, it would be impossible to tell the difference from GHC's actual implementation of `IO` (from within the pure fragment of Haskell that excludes things like `unsafePerformIO`). So in the end it doesn't matter whether you consider it "really" pure; you can still program as if it is.

Comment: You're not passing anything to `main`. You're defining `main`. Nowhere in your code is `main` actually invoked; that happens in the runtime.

Comment: Doesn't that definition of `main` have that side effect during execution of your code? @sepp2k

Comment: @user129393192: the idea of the main is that you make a recipe of functions that are all in itself pure, that you then execute. If you use `print "foo"`, that is pure and constant, since `print "foo"` does not print, it is when you "run" `print "foo"` that sometihing is written to the console. To some extent is equivalent to `State`, except that the "state" here is the entire state of the machine, the network, the internet, the universe so to speak.

Comment: Haskell code doesn't get "executed". I think of it this way: the Haskell *runtime* executes `IO` actions; Haskell itself is a DSL for *defining* `IO` actions.

Answer (score 3):

I think the crucial point of confusion is this, from your comments:

> Doesn't that definition of `main` have that side effect during execution of your code?

*No* it doesn't! Defining `main` doesn't have any side effects. –Well, defining something generally doesn't mean much anyway in lazy Haskell, but also *forcing the `main` action to normal form* wouldn't have any side effects:

```
ghci> let sideEffect :: IO (); sideEffect = putStrLn "I'M HAVING AN EFFECT!"
ghci> sideEffect `seq` 0
0
```

See, nothing is printed.

<sup>(This demonstration isn't all that meaningful; [`seq`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.19.1.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:seq) only forces to *weak head normal form* and may in fact not force anything at all if the compiler can prove this doesn't change anything about strictness properties. But the actual argument stands.)</sup>

The happening-of-side-effects is completely separate from the pure things going on in the Haskell definitions. As already said, what you're doing purely is *defining a recipe* for how side effects are supposed to happen. This doesn't mean they ever actually will happen. It's like a criminal making up a plan for a bank robbery whilst in prison: he can scheme as evil doings as he wishes, but nothing is actually going to happen because he can't leave the prison.

*Running the program* that contains this `main` action is a completely different story. Now any side effects that our recipe mentions will get unleashed on the world.

You might now ask: isn't this just the same in other programming languages? After all, compiling a program in C or Java also doesn't launch the side effects, only *running the compiled program* does.

The difference is that in Haskell, you can still evaluate functions and do computations and all whilst being sure side effects won't happen. This is handy because you can try out stuff in GHCi, or unit-test individual functions, or use a web framework dealing with user-defined code, and rest asured that no side effects or dependence on global state will muddle the results.
By contrast, in C, when evaluating a function (of which you only know the signature) you can never know whether it will also print something to the terminal or connect to a remote server or whatnot. (Well, you can sandbox it, but that's crude and unwieldy.)

Of course if you bring [`unsafePerformIO`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.19.1.0/docs/System-IO-Unsafe.html#v:unsafePerformIO) into the picture, all of it breaks down: with it, ordinary evaluations *can* also have side effects.

```
ghci> :m +System.IO.Unsafe 
ghci> let unsafeSideEffect :: (); unsafeSideEffect = unsafePerformIO (putStrLn "I'M HAVING AN EFFECT!")
ghci> unsafeSideEffect `seq` 0
I'M HAVING AN EFFECT!
0
```

But I don't consider `unsafePerformIO` to be really part of the Haskell language; it's an escape hatch mostly used for foreign-function calling and for low-level optimisations.