# Is a function which just prints its arguments pure?

Tags: bash, functional-programming

Suppose you have a function which just prints its arguments formatted:

```
__print_spec_result() {
  printf '%s  %s%s (%.3f s)%s\n' "$1" "$2" "$cyan" "$3" "$reset"
}
```

Here, `$1` and `$2` are arguments to the function, `$cyan` and `$reset` are constants.

Is this function pure in the functional sense?

Comment: Isn't printing considered a side effect?

Comment: Well, a pure function is pointless if it doesn't return anything, right?  This function, however, has purpose beyond its return value...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No because printf is impure.

See from [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pure_function):

> printf() is impure because it causes output to an I/O device as a side
>   effect

And from another SO Question and his answer:
[Why is printf() an impure function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11919894/why-is-printf-an-impure-function)

> printf is impure because its result has "side effects" --
>   specifically, it prints something on the screen (or in a file, etc).
>   If it were pure, then you could call it a billion times and be sure
>   nothing bad would happen. But if you actually call printf a million
>   times, there certainly is a difference to the user -- it fills up his
>   screen (or disk space, or whatever). So clearly it's not pure.

Comment: Since this is bash where commands are used like `x=$(factorial 5)` then printing functions as return. `echo` is the identity "function" .