# Is this pure functional? using a value in the nested (Closure like) function

Tags: javascript, functional-programming

Using a value in the nested (Closure like) function such as:

```
const f1= () => {
    const a = 1;
    const f2 = () => a;
    return f2;
    };
```

`f2` does not have arg of `a`, but returns `a` of the upper-scope of `f1`.

Comment: It is functional and you're using closure the functional way too. You should post this on codereview.stackexchange.com instead though.

Comment: Relevant https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B,_C,_K,_W_system (see K-combinator)

Comment: @randy Why do you recommend posting on Code Review? There is no reviewable code here. Please read [_A guide to Code Review for Stack Overflow users_](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/q/5777).

Comment: sorry, I simply forgotten to add the return value of f1. I modified the ode.

Comment: @200_succes because the question is open for comments on any part of code, it is not a question closed Down to one answer and the user asks for improving answers, not a solution

Answer (score 2):

**Yes**.

`a` is a constant and referentially transparent. It doesn't matter that `f2` is a closure as long as it does not close over mutable state.

Comment: Thanks Bergi, but I don't like to use a buzz-word "referentially transparent", many argue on this term and disagreement there. Can you view in other way?

Comment: `a` is referentially transparent by all definitions of the term :-) About what disagreements are you concerned specifically?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4865616/purity-vs-referential-transparency?rq=1 and I agree to the answer#1, the word "referentially transparent" is not useful, and personally, I avoid to explain using that term in FP context.

Comment: I'm not terminology-versed enough to find a better term, but I think that [any of these definitions](http://stackoverflow.com/q/210835/1048572) works for `a`.

Comment: Speaking of terms: Wikipedia states that [purely functional languages](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purely_functional) guarantee the equivalence of call-by-name, call-by-value and call-by-need evaluation. JS pursues only the call-by-value strategy. So does  **purely functional** in the context of JS just mean **pure functions**?

Comment: @Iven Yes, pure means pure, because the actual evaluation strategy does not matter.