# Why is println considered an impure function?

Tags: scala, functional-programming, pure-function

I'm reading the book programming in scala, and it is said :

> ... in this case , its side effect is printing to the standard output stream.

and I don't see where is the side effect, since, for the same input, println will print the same output (I think )

**UPDATE**
for example any time we call :

```
println(5)
```

it will print **5**, I don't see a case where calling `println(5)` will print a value other than 5 !!

Comment: if this answers your question, I'll delete my answer https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/40297/271736

Comment: Answers at [What is referential transparency?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/210835/217324) seem relevant here.

Comment: related (lol) https://stackoverflow.com/q/4865616/5986907

Comment: You confused side effect (not referential transparent) with deterministic. `println` is a deterministic function but in order to be pure it must also be RT.

Comment: Because it does something other than compute a result and return it.

Comment: If you can't see where the side effect is, I recommend plugging in your monitor. ;)

Answer (score 8):

You can tell if an expression has a side effect by replacing the expression with its result. If the program changes *meaning*, there's a side effect. For example,

```
println(5)
```

is a different program to

```
()
```

That is, a side effect is any observable effect that isn't encoded in the result of evaluating an expression. Here the result is `()`, but there's nothing in that value that encodes the fact that 5 has now appeared somewhere on your screen.

Comment: Actually that is not a good definition of a _"side-effect"_ - A side effect may be defined as anything that breaks referential transparency. What you tried to show here was RT but your example is wrong. Since executing something multiple times should do the same thing mutiple times - Rather, `val a = println("hello"); val b = (a, a)` should be the same as `val b = (pritnln("hello"), println("hello"))`.

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez perhaps my example's not clear, but I don't think it's wrong. I'm essentially pointing out the difference between the program `println(5)` and `()`. Or did you mean the last sentence?

Comment: Yeah but you weren't clear about it. Since,as I said, the problem is not calling something multiple times, the problem is if replacing a reference with its definition would have that impact.

Comment: I'd say it's wrong because it's perfectly possible for something to have a side effect and be idempotent so repeating it doesn't change the effect. E.g. assignment to a mutable variable; how can you distinguish `x = 1` and `x = 1; x = 1; x = 1`?

Comment: @AlexeyRomanov I've edited my answer. But for your example, I don't see how the second and third assignments are side effects. Nothing's changing at all there.

Comment: It's simpler to classify `x = 1` as having a side-effect, full stop, regardless of context, rather than saying "it only has a side effect if x isn't already 1". The two buckets are "never side-effects" and "sometimes/always side-effects". It isn't normally useful to distinguish the "sometimes" and "always" cases from each other.

Answer (score 6):

The side effect is in the state of the computer. Each time you call `println()` the state of memory changes in order to display given value to the terminal. Or more generally, the state of the standard output stream is changed.

Comment: Partially true, execute any operation would the state of the instruction counter, thus anything is a side effect. The definition of side-effect derivates from the definition of referential transparency, which many people define in terms of modifications to a shared mutable state.

Comment: in this way, any function, operation.... will be impure, since it change, state of memory cpu.....,

Answer (score 6):

Consider the following analogy

```
var out: String = ""
def myprintln(s: String) = {
  out += s // this non-local mutation makes me impure
  ()
}
```

Here `myprintln` is impure because beside returning value `()` it also mutates non-local variable `out` as a side-effect. Now imagine `out` to be the stream vanilla `println` mutates.

Comment: thank you, for responding, it is clear that your function is impure, however, why println(), as defined in scala, is not pure

Comment: @aName Because besides returning value `()` it also mutates non-local state in [`System.out`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#out).

Comment: I think the crucial fact missing from this answer is that println adds a newline character to the input.

Answer (score 2):

Nice answers were already given to this question, but let me add my two cents.

If you will look inside `println` function essentially it is the same as `java.lang.System.out.println()` - so when you invoke Scala's standard library `println` method under the hood it invokes method `println` on `PrintStream` object instance which is declared as field `out` in `System` class (or more precisely `outVar` in `Console` object), which changes it internal state. This can be considered as another one explanation why `println` is impure function.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 2):

It has to do with the concept of *referential transparency*. An expression is referentially transparent if you can **substitute it with its evaluated result without changing the program**.

When an expression is not referentially transparent we say that it has *side effects*.

```scala
f(println("effect"), println("effect"))
// isn't really equivalent to!
val x = println("effect")
f(x, x)
```

while

```scala
import cats.effect.IO

def printlnIO(line: String): IO[Unit] = IO(println(line))

f(printlnIO("effect"), printlnIO("effect"))
// is equivalent to
val x = printlnIO("effect")
f(x, x)
```

You can find a more detailed explanation here: https://typelevel.org/blog/2017/05/02/io-monad-for-cats.html

Comment: I don't see why f(x,x) is different from f(println("effect"), println("effect")) !!

Comment: `f(println("effect"), println("effect"))` is going to print two times in console "effect" while `val x = println("effect");f(x,x)` is going to print once.

Comment: what is the definition of the function f