# How to sleep or delay the thread in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, compiler-errors, delay, sleep

This really shouldn't be so difficult to find an answer to, but alas I don't... I want to delay the next execution step in a `do` block. I have found the functions
`delay`,
`sleep`,
`nanosleep` and
`usleep`.

And also this question, that doesn't cover how to use any of these, however: [Sleep in Haskell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25576184/sleep-in-haskell).

I am getting the same error for all of these, so probably I am doing something wrong fundamentally:

> `Variable not in scope: delay :: Integer -> IO a0`

This is my test snippet:

```
main = do
  {
    putStrLn "line 1"
  ; delay 2
  ; putStrLn "line 2"
  }
```

Googling the error does not actually yield anything useful for some reason.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Well, you have to import `Control.Concurrent` first:

```
import Control.Concurrent

threadDelay 1000000 --sleep for a million microseconds, or one second
```

Comment: Ok, not very useful error message. I would expect something like `unknown symbol "delay"`... in fact, it does seem to know the symbol, as it knowns the function's signature. So then why do I need to import the definition? And also... what would I need to import to use that actual `delay` function rather than `threadDelay`?

Comment: It knows the type because of _type inference_. The function with the _required_ signature doesn't exist, though, so you get an error message. Then, the `delay` function is non-standard, and you need to install a 3rd party package called `concurrent-extra`, as the link suggests. Then you `import Control.Concurrent.Thread.Delay`, and that's it. I'm not sure why you need that specific function since `threadDelay` is the standard way to suspend program execution in Haskell.

Comment: @ForceBru When I first started looking for a delay function, the first search term which came up was this extra package, and I mistakenly used that for a while before realising there was a version in Control.Concurrent. So possibly just search engines turning up the wrong thing.